# How do I get an XCOM hero?

Tags: xcom-2

How do I get an XCOM Hero? I saw this screenshot of a secret XCOM hero that says:

[image]

Apparently, getting an XCOM hero disables achievements for the rest of the playthrough.  Are there other XCOM heroes, or is this the only one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After getting your squad together, if you rename your squad member in the customization settings, if you change the name to a specific name the game will make it a "special" XCOM hero.  There are two others you can get as XCOM heroes, all discovered through the default.ini configuration settings:

```
 ;SUPER SOLDIERS!! 
 ;Sid Meier BodyPartTemplateConfig=(PartType="Head",
 TemplateName="Supersoldier1_M",
 ArchetypeName="Head_Supersoldier1.ARC_Head_Supersoldier1",
 Gender=eGender_Male, Race=eRace_Caucasian, SpecializedType=true)
 ;Beaglerush BodyPartTemplateConfig=(PartType="Head",
 TemplateName="Supersoldier2_M",
 ArchetypeName="Head_Supersoldier2.ARC_Head_Supersoldier2",
 Gender=eGender_Male, SpecializedType=true) ;VanDoorn
 BodyPartTemplateConfig=(PartType="Head",
 TemplateName="Supersoldier3_M",
 ArchetypeName="Head_Supersoldier3.ARC_Head_Supersoldier3",
 Gender=eGender_Male, SpecializedType=true)
```

So basically, you just need to rename your squad member to either:

- Peter Van Doorn
- Sid Meier
- Beaglerush

[image]

In order to get an XCOM hero!

For reference, Peter Van Doorn is a [famous NPC you can rescue in XCOM: Enemy Unknown.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/3gg2ia/who_is_van_doorn/ctxxzkq). Sid Meier is a famous developer who is the creator of the Civilization series and director of Creative Development for Firaxis Games. Beaglerush is a famous XCOM streamer and youtuber.

Comment: Are the differences between a Hero and a regular soldier just cosmetic?

Comment: They have ridiculously high stats, hence the achievements getting disabled.